# Extract a small number of elements from a long sequence

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

To extract a few elements from a sequence, Scala can use case match as the following:

```
row match {
            case Seq(a, b, c, d, e, f) => Seq(a,f)
            case _ => logger.warn("Warning")
            }
```

What if the original sequence is very long (e.g 1k), and only want to extract a small number of elements (e.g 2 or 3).

In order to not write up all the elements in the original sequence (e.g, omit 1k elements between a and f), is there a way to do case match in Scala, maybe something like this:

```
 row match {
                case Seq(..., a, ..., f,...) => Seq(a,f)
                case _ => logger.warn("Warning")
                }
```

Or something similar to SQL doing `select a, f from Seq`?

Comment: You can easily extract elements from head, but not random elements without a custom extractors

Comment: `Seq(row(5), row(77))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jwvh's answer, using index to access the elements works perfect for this question.

A sample could be `Seq(row(5), row(77))`